# Conditional Sum using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want a code in VBA, which will get me a sum for a category (which is displayed as a number), note that this number is changing and not in serial order, as soon as it changes, I want the sum for that particular sub-division. Example- say Towns is a category and Ward is sub category, so my data is displayed as following:
So lets say the data says that town numbered 100 has 3 wards (1001, 1002, 1003) with their population data,and town numbered 123 has 2 wards (1231, 1232) with their total population data correspondingly, now I want to sum the total population in town 100 and similarly for town 123..and so on.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you looked at the "Subtotals" feature of Excel? It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a Pivot Table will do what you want and you won't need any custom VBA code at all.

Comment: Actually I have a huge data set, and I have to do this across many excel sheets.

Comment: Read the instructions on how to ask a good question, then come back & update your original question post. We'll be happy to help you over specific hurdles, but you're not going to find many willing to just do your work for you.